# Create sqlite db in .NET maui app and it works fine. Copy db to pc then copy back to device and it crashes app

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, maui

I am using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite in .NET Maui (Android) to create a SQLite database in the "Downloads" folder on an Android mobile device if one doesn't exist when the target app is loaded.  This process works fine. A valid readable, writeable database is created with no issues.  However,   after closing the mobile app and connecting the Android mobile device to my pc via USB, these are the steps I follow leading to my issue:

1. Copy the very same SQLite database created in the Downloads folder by the mobile app to a folder on my local pc
2. Delete the original mobile device database from the "Downloads" folder
3. Copy the "copied" original SQLite database from the PC back to the mobile device "Downloads" folder.
4. Restart the mobile app.

The app crashes every time I try to open after this point.  I verified that the database is not "read-only".  I am able to open the file in DB Browser for SQLite and verified there is no encryption or corruption affecting the file.  The only error I have been able to find in the logs is "**Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException:** 'SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.'"  Nothing regarding permissions, or anything else that I can see.

I accept that this may be something simple, or I may be breaking mobile app protocol by using the "Downloads" folder for my app database (the same issue occurs when I store the db in the app directory fyi).  Can anyone advise on either a better way to move a database from a local pc to an Android mobile app, or a fix to the copying issue highlighted above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you actually tried catching the exception and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: Just want to point out few things. Valid, readable and writable "database" is more or less every blank file. Nothing special. What I recommend - programmatically copy it. Directly to your database directory. No symbols, no numbers. File name "abc". It should work.

Comment: I have a feeling this has something to do with latest android permissions to let apps access files they created without permissions, but files that were created elsewhere (you pasted it from pc) must be accessed by app that has adequate permissions to access files on device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have in your manifest:

inside `<application   android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" >`

then

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

as this file is now considered "not created by your app" no-matter that it resides in your app folder

Comment: Unfortunately I am still having the issue.  This app existed previously in WinCE using ActiveSync to sync the data.  There doesn't seem to be an equivalent solution for Android.  Anyone know of an open source solution for syncing a sqlite database file from pc to mobile device? I currently have a solution that will connect from PC to mobile android device via bluetooth and copy sqlite db from pc folder to the downloads folder on the device.  It crashes the app on loading with error "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException Message=SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'".

Comment: check the downloaded file extension. when you run our of options just implement importing received data file to existing db. and at that point you might find why you had the initial problem, my bet its either permissions problem either the filename is bad either the file itsself is corrupt (wrong version, header etc) for the sqlite library you are using on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by downgrading the Android version to 29 and explicitly requesting WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions using Xamarin.Essentials permissions methods.  Not sure why, but the ability to write to external storage is not supported in Android 30 and above.  I will eventually need to upgrade above Android 29 but this buys me time to figure out a longer term solution. Thanks for your help everyone.